# color for beamer

Tags: beamer, color

Could you help me to change the color for beamer. I'll defend my PhD thesis next friday and we have to follow some orientation for presentation's format in our university.
So, I'm using `\usetheme{Berlin}`, and this is the output
[image]

but it shoul be black around (top and bottom) and grey into the page background, like this
[image]

Could you help me please?
And, is it possible to put the name before the title?
Thank you!!!

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{bg=normal text.bg!90!black}

\title[Prova de Doutoramento em Economia | Coimbra, 15 de Abil de 2016]{\Large \bf Políticas Monetária e Orçamental e Ciclos Económicos nos Mercados Emergentes}

\author[Gilson Pina]{Gilson Manuel Gomes Pina}

\normalsize

\date{
{\begin{minipage}[c]{16cm}
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Orientadores:} \\ 
\small Professor Doutor Pedro Bação (FEUC)\\
\small Professor Doutor Ricardo M. Sousa (EEG/UM)
\end{flushleft}
 \end{minipage}}\\
\vspace*{0.5cm}
{Prova de Doutoramento em Economia}\\
{\small  Coimbra, 15 de Abril de 2016}
}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Sum\'{a}rio}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  exemple
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am guessing that English is not your first language and that your greeting was not intended the way it sounds. In any case, I've removed it as it isn't needed here anyway. That way, your post won't inadvertently cause offence. [Not that it was awful, but not really a good way to start a post to people you hope will help you!]

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal document (code) we can play with. Try looking in the manual. Don't worry about the colours. Look for something with a structure close to the one you need: a single colour block without section information in the header, for example.

Comment: off-topic: @Gilson Good luck & all the best for your defense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the colours in beamer, you can use

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{206,202,177}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=mycolor}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}
```

Note: I got the RGB values from your image, but check if this are the correct values or if they were altered during conversion.

---

But if you really need the exact same layout as your screenshot, you either have to write your own theme or fake it by using images of empty slides as background images.

[image]

**Full MWE:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{bg=normal text.bg!90!black}

\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{206,202,177}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=mycolor}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}

\title[Prova de Doutoramento em Economia | Coimbra, 15 de Abil de 2016]{\Large \bf Políticas Monetária e Orçamental e Ciclos Económicos nos Mercados Emergentes}

\author[Gilson Pina]{Gilson Manuel Gomes Pina}

\normalsize

\date{
{\begin{minipage}[c]{16cm}
\begin{flushleft}
\textbf{Orientadores:} \\ 
\small Professor Doutor Pedro Bação (FEUC)\\
\small Professor Doutor Ricardo M. Sousa (EEG/UM)
\end{flushleft}
 \end{minipage}}\\
\vspace*{0.5cm}
{Prova de Doutoramento em Economia}\\
{\small  Coimbra, 15 de Abril de 2016}
}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Sum\'{a}rio}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  example
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Gilson You are welcome. Good luck for your defence!